# Handling whitespace with jQuery .val() method. (Using Codeigniter)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am confused on how the .val() method in jQuery handles whitespace (if it is a jQuery problem at all).

My example is using an AJAX suggestion box feature which I'm slowly developing. It uses Codeigniter as the framework.

I have this jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#suggestbox").hide();
    $("#searchboxinput").live("keyup", function(){
        if ($("#searchboxinput").val().length==0){
            $("#suggestbox").fadeOut(100);
        }else{
            $("#suggestbox").fadeIn(100);
            $("#sugresultcontain").load('http://localhost/ajaxtest/ajaxhandle/suggest/'+$("#searchboxinput").val()+' #loadsuggest');
        };
    });
});
```

The '#suggestboxinput' is a text input as shown:

```
<div id="content" class="clear">
    <div id="searchwrap" class="clear">
        <div id="searchbox" class="float-left"><input id="searchboxinput" name="" value="" type="text"></div>
        <div id="searchbutton" class="float-right"><input id="searchbuttoninput" name="" type="button" value="Go"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="suggestbox" class="clear">
        <div id="suggesthead">Suggestions:</div>
        <div id="sugresultcontain"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I then have (Using code igniter) a method which handles the .load() as shown:

```
public function suggest($q=''){

        $suggest = $this->ajax_handle->suggest();

        for($i=0; $i<count($suggest); $i++){
            $db[$i] = $suggest[$i]['firstname'].' '.$suggest[$i]['lastname'];
        }

        if(strlen($q)>0){
            $sugstr = '';
            $e = 0;

            for($f=0; $f<count($db); $f++){
                if (strtolower($q)==strtolower(substr($db[$f],0,strlen($q)))){
                    $sugresult[$e] = $db[$f];
                    $e++;
                }
            }

            if(isset($sugresult)){
                $data['sugresult'] = $sugresult;
                $this->load->view('ajaxref/suggest', $data);
            }else{
                $this->load->view('ajaxref/suggest');
            }
        }else{
            $this->load->view('ajaxref/suggest');
        }
    }
```

This works almost as intended, if I load the page then use the text input the names from the database do show (according to text field). It works fine if I type the first name and will continue to show no matter how many spaces I put after the field (which is perfect).

However, the problem lies with typing the surname even after just a single space (Dominic Sore) or even just the first letter or the last name (Dominic S). No names show in the suggestion box.

I had read that using a '+' symbol in the input box will work. I tested it, and it did work (Dominic+Sore outputs Dominic Sore in suggestion box). Understandably though, I cannot have users type a '+' for every space they want to use.

So I am just wondering how do I handle this? I've been reading a lot but I cannot find a solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try [`$.trim`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) method:

> Remove the whitespace from the beginning and end of a string.

```
var txt = $.trim($("#searchboxinput").val()).replace(' ', '+')
```

Comment: Perfecto! Such a simple solution, I did look at trim but I think I was confused on it's function.

Comment: @DominicSore yes, trim is one of jQuery [utility](http://api.jquery.com/category/utilities/) functions and can be a confusing one at first glance.

Comment: Is there any way in which it differs from the native JavaScript [`trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/string/trim)?

Comment: @DavidThomas no, maybe browser support.

Comment: Thanks! I read the jQuery page, and wasn't sure if I'd missed something. And...good grief; every answer in this question's been accepted once (or more times) in the past ten minutes... =/

Comment: @DavidThomas yes, and at the end there is no accepted answer :)

Comment: Ah, the fleeting nature of rewards, and appreciation. ...I'm coming over all *zen*... =)

Comment: @DavidThomas ah, yes, me too :)

Comment: Sorry, the the first accept I didn't mean to press, then the other answer made logical sense but hasn't worked. This answer is accepted as it does the job. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: @DominicSore no worries. it's your right to accept the answer that solves the problem :)

Comment: @DominicSore, my apologies if I offended you in any way, I only meant to tease a little. And it is, as undefined rightly says, absolutely your right to choose. =) Though your comment concerns me, as it (obviously) suggests that my answer didn't work. Still! If `trim()` *did* then it's all good in the end! =)

Comment: @DavidThomas - No offence taken at all. I am very new to the site and still grasping how it all works, if anything I thought I was causing a problem. I did try your method - i'll post a comment on it explaining results.

Answer (score 2):

Given that using `+` works, it might be worth using `encodeURIComponent()` to url-encode the variable before submitting it for matching, to give:

```
$("#sugresultcontain").load('http://localhost/ajaxtest/ajaxhandle/suggest/'+encodeURIComponent($("#searchboxinput").val())+' #loadsuggest');
```

Alternatively, you could do a simple replace:

```
$('#searchboxinput').val().replace(/\w/g,'+');
```

But `encodeURIComponent` is more reliable, and will properly encode apostrophes (O'Neill), as well as space characters.

References:

- [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).
- [`string.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/string/replace).

Comment: I did try your method (top method) and the result was that I could type the name and as soon as I pressed space ('Dominic ') the suggestions would not appear.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, the issue lies in the line

```
$("#sugresultcontain").load('http://localhost/ajaxtest/ajaxhandle/suggest/'+$("#searchboxinput").val()+' #loadsuggest');
```

Think about it this way, you are making a string by concatenating several part. Say your input has `"   something"` in it, that means you are loading:

```
'http://localhost/ajaxtest/ajaxhandle/suggest/    something #loadsuggest'
```

This will obviously not work as intended. What you need to do is trim the value from the input, and better yet make sure it contains only valid url characters (otherwise a / or ? in the input could break the query for the same reason)

Something along those lines:

```
var suggest_url_part = encodeURIComponent($("#searchboxinput").val().trim());
if (suggest_url_part.length) {    
  $("#sugresultcontain").load('http://localhost/ajaxtest/ajaxhandle/suggest/' + suggest_url_part + '#loadsuggest');
}
```

Comment: Hmn, I see your point. It make logical sense, however, I just tried to use this method and the problem came back?